# Integrated Windows Authentication and fastcgi.impersonate parameter

Tags: php, iis, windows-authentication

I have a PHP project running on IIS6 (FastCGI mode). If I enable "Integrated Windows Authentication" with enabled fastcgi.impersonate option in php.ini everything works fine in every browser, but if I disable fastcgi.impersonate in php.ini I get the different behavior of browsers:

- IE opens the standart windows authentication dialog, but even if I specify my password 100% well it not authenticates me.
- Chrome just show me ERR_INVALID_AUTH_CREDENTIALS and nothing more happens.
- FF still works fine and does NTLM authentication automaticaly.

How can I fix this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We set forced NTLM authentication on IIS instead of Negotiate and it works fine.